# how can I fix that problem. I cannot add model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, nuget-package

[image] how can I fix that problem. I unintalled then installed a new one but it cannot work. I even cannot add controller. Thanks for read my question. Please tell me the answer if you know. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you added that NuGet package to your project? If so, try removing and re-adding it. Watch the output from the package manager as you add it. By the way, in most dialog boxes, if you press `<ctrl>+C`, the contents of the dialog box will be added to the clipboard (allowing you to add the error message to your question as text). Not sure if that works with Visual Studio these days

Comment: I already added NuGet. ah, I cannot add 6.4.4 version. I installed 6.1.3

Comment: Well, you appear to have a dependency on v6.4.4. Why can't you add that version? Can you add a later one? Is this the .NET Framework or Core (or 5 or 6 or 7)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add valid nuget sources in package manager.
To do that open tools tab then nuget package manager and then nuget package sources
Add new record to sources by using the form at the end of window, with this string as url

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

And you sould be fine.